# firefox extensions in the repository: what is the reason/purpose?

Tags: arch-linux, firefox

What is the reason why to package (thus spend time and resources) Firefox extensions in the Arch Linux repository[1] ?

Honestly I can see only one good reason: the **kiosk** case, where *everything* except internet navigation is inhibited.
(also in this case one can install needed extensions beside Firefox, prior to *lock* the kiosk...)

Where negative effects of having extensions installed this way are:

- hard job to maintain them (creation/update/issue...)
- not automatically updated by Firefox
- out-to-date version due to frequent update
- only a bunch of extensions are in the repo

What am I missing?

---

*I do not know if other distributions (repositories) have them*

[1] https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=firefox+extension&maintainer=&flagged=

Comment: Is your question “Why are firefox extensions in the application repository, when I can install them manually?”.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your question is ”Why are firefox extensions in the application repository, when I can install them manually?”

Then the answer is why not, this argument can be made for **everything** in the repository. I don't use them, because I like to keep my web-browser more up to date, than the one in the repository. But this could be true of any application (there is nothing special about a web-browser).

Comment: I completely disagree with you! Extensions are much more simple than applications: the latter needs a compilation and a deep integration with the whole system (libs, filesystem hierarchy, etc.); the former it's like a sandboxed app...

Comment: It is a continuum. There are some packages like you say that need compiling, some that need deep integration, some that don't need compiling (python, shell-scripts, etc), some that need no integration. So yes the firefox extensions may not need much to install them, but some for a lot of other stuff. Where should we draw the line? And if I have to do it manually, this adds a lot of complexity for each package that I need to install manually.